# How to subtract an Inputstream from an other one?

Tags: java, groovy, compare, inputstream

I have two Socketconnections. The first one I'm only listening and get data via InputStream:

```
> NormalMessage a
> NormalMessage b
> NormalMessage c
> NormalMessage d
```

The second one is the same, but I also send requests and get answers within the other messages:

```
> NormalMessage a
< request 1
> Answer for 1a
> Answer for 1b
> Answer for 1c
> NormalMessage b
< request 2
> Answer for 2a
> Answer for 2b
> Answer for 2c
> Answer for 2d
> NormalMessage c
> NormalMessage d
```

What i want is to know what lines of the InputStream are the answer for my request. In my opinion I have no other way then open to connections and compare the Streams.
In my mind is something like:

```
InputStream answerStream = new MySpecialInputStream(basicStream, substractedStream);
```

an the answerStream only contains:

```
> Answer for 1a
> Answer for 1b
> Answer for 1c
> Answer for 2a
> Answer for 2b
> Answer for 2c
> Answer for 2d
```

Any idea?

I'm looking for a fundamental concept/idea for this problem.
In my current case it's written in groovy/java and both InputStreams are BufferedReader - so atm a string line based solution (as MySpecialBufferedReader) would be adequate.
A code example would be also welcome, but not needed.

Thx and kind regards.

Comment: Can we assume, that you can not distinquish an "Answer" from an "NormalMessage"?  As in "NormalMessage" are just answers to other questions you dont have asked but others (as e.g. a hub)?  Can't you just mark your questions and have the other side put that marker back into the answer?

Comment: Yes that's right, I can't distinguish. When I do a request I just get more answers, but the structure of the answers and "normal messages" are same.
Normal Messages could be answers for requests of others or just status informations.
I have no way to force a specific sign in the answers just for me, I can just modify the client side.

And a small little addon I didn't pointed on:
It could be that the second SocketConnections starts later then the first.